# What is the Facebook Font Used in Messaging?

Tags: facebook, fonts

When you visit a Facebook profile/page, and click message... you're prompted with a modal, which has a very nice font for the body.

Here's an example I found on Google:
http://blog.sendoutcards.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Screen-Shot-2013-11-18-at-10.27.56-AM.png

Does anyone know what the font is called that is used for Facebook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif. On mac you'll get lucida grande & on windows you'll get tahoma

Comment: And on Linux you get?

Comment: depends on available font